# bc: using "scale" with bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

Easily, I'm writing a script that needs some values with 2 digits after floating point. Trying to use `bc` I don't understand how use "scale", i.e.

```
A=12 ; bc <<< $(($A/5))
```

it's correct, but adding "scale" leads to an error:

```
A=12 ; bc <<< 'scale=2;$(($A/5))'

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace single quotes with double; because with single quotes `$A` in your equation is not expanded, rather considered as literally `$A` not `12`

```
A=12 ; bc <<< "scale=2;$(($A/5))"
2
```

Also, inside $(()) to variable does not need to be specified as `$A`, just `A` will do, e.g.

```
A=12 ; bc <<< "scale=2;$((A/5))"
2
```

Next, when doing $(()) you invoke subshell, which is not what you want to do because `bc` does not do anything then. Try this

```
A=12 ; bc <<< "scale=2; $A/5"
2.40
```

Comment: Hello, I modified my question. I need the result with floating point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
A=12;echo 'scale=2;'"$A / 5"|bc -l
```